# Sending Immediate email when data update in Extension ( Password Reset)

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

I want to send immediate email ( password reset email ) from Marketing cloud when data pass from through API. i want to send email  as soon as data is updated in data extension.
can anyone please suggest possible solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As EazyE told, I also think you should use a trigger send. Regarding your use case described in your comment, it is compatible with this feature. Moreoever, it's the best way to make real time communication.

Let's see if the following thing answers to your use case :

Step 1 : The third party make the Trigger Send API Call
 -> This will insert data in the TriggerSendDataExtension

Step 2 : Retrieve the missing data with [the AMPScript lookup function](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/lookup.htm) directly inside the HTML Email linked to the Trigger Send.
 -> You can use the data inserted in the TriggerSendDataExtension in order to lookup the data in your main data extension.

Comment: Thanks Pleb! it works!

Answer (score 1):

You should evaluate using the TriggeredSend functionality listed [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/transactional-messaging-api.htm)

> Transactional messaging is immediate, automated, non-promotional messaging, such as order confirmation messages, password reset emails, and bank balance inquiry messages. Use the Marketing Cloud Transactional Messaging REST API to email personalized transactional messages to your customers. To receive immediate notifications about whether your message was sent and other events, use the Marketing Cloud Event Notification Service.

You can use a [TriggeredSend Data extension](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_create_triggered_send_data_extension.htm&type=5) to store the data you pass in the TS API call.

Comment: Hello, @EazyE thanks for these details.
We can do this but the requirement is different- 
The third party is not sending the email data they are sending me data related to that email- and I need to do the lookup to get the email from our main data extension then trigger a send!
How I can achieve this?